# Unable to open google map in android emulator's

Tags: android

In Android Emulator i am getting below Logcat Error:

```
03-11 04:44:56.663: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(403): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.map/com.map.MapDemo}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.map.MapDemo in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.map-1.apk]
```

Cannot find package com.map in AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check following things

check if this line is included in your manifest file as child of `manifest`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

add below line as child of `application` ONLY in manifest

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

Next Right click on your project folder -> properties -> android -> check if you have selected Google API

also check if you have created AVD with your Google API.
If again you need help in any of this let us know.

Answer (score 2):

You will be able to use Google maps if your emulator is setup to use Google API's. If you do not have already, create a new emulator with target platform as Google API from the drop-down.

Answer (score 1):

Jst take map.jar file from inbuild application by importing.

c:\androidsdk\add-ons\addon_google_apis_google_inc_7\libs\map.jar
in your eclipse project there will by jar files folder. add external jar files form that and take map.jar.

then give internet permission.  and also get api key.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have added your MapActivity class to the Android manifest using:

```
<activity android:name="com.map.MapDemo" android:label="MapDemo"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check whether u've installed google packages in ur eclipse....If u haven't installed now install google packages by selecting "Android SDK and AVD Manager" in window...And select installed packages in the left side then u wil get a packages on the right side select third party packages and install google packages as per ur requirement...